# How to pass values to model that was trained by dataset encoded with pd.dummies? I am getting Value Error: Unable to convert array

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

dataset = pd.read_csv('test_scores.csv')
columns = dataset.columns.values.tolist()
columns.remove('student_id')
columns.remove('posttest')

X = dataset[columns]
y = dataset['posttest']

x = pd.get_dummies(X)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.15)

regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.round(y_pred)

pickle_out = open("model.pkl", mode = "wb") 
pickle.dump(regressor, pickle_out) 
pickle_out.close()
```

Streamlit form:

```
school = st.selectbox("School", (school_list))
school_setting = st.selectbox("School Setting", (setting_list))
school_type = st.selectbox("School Type", (school_type_list))
classroom = st.selectbox("Classroom", (classroom_list))
teaching_method = st. selectbox("Teaching Method", (teaching_method_list))
n_student = st.number_input("Number of students in the classroom")
gender = st.selectbox("Gender", (gender_list))
lunch = st.selectbox("Do you qualify for Lunch?", (lunch_list))
pretest = st.text_input("Pretest score")
```

For the model trained using above, I have tried using the below code to get

```
score = model.predict( [[school, school_setting, school_type, classroom, teaching_method, n_student, student_id, gender, lunch, pretest]])
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric'
```

Is this because the trained model is trained with dummies and would only take inputs as 0 or 1? How to fix this?

I am using [this dataset from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/kwadwoofosu/predict-test-scores-of-students).

Sample of data I am working with:

[image]

Comment: you are not selecting your data from the DataFrame... try using `model.predict(X_test[columns])` where `columns` is the list of columns names.

Comment: Actually those are variables storing the data accepted @AntoineDubuis